# After successful selenium install getting ImportError: No module named 'Selenium'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, anaconda, importerror

I am receiving an import error after what appears to be a successful selenium install. Here is the message I received when I initially installed selenium:

```
My-Mac-Pro:~ Mymachine$ pip3 install selenium
Collecting selenium
  Downloading selenium-3.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (931kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 942kB 490kB/s 
Installing collected packages: selenium
Successfully installed selenium-3.4.3
```

When I attempt to import selenium I get the following error message:

```
from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm 
CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", 
line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'selenium'
```

If I try to reinstall selenium I get the following message indicating the installed selenium module is where it should be:

```
My-Mac-Pro:~ Mymachine$ pip3 install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in 
./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

If I navigate to the ./anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages folder I see the selenium folder. I've worked my way through every posted question on this topic I could find but have not been able to solve the problem. If anybody has any ideas I would appreciate the help. I am using the Anaconda Python install.

Comment: Are you running in Pycharm?

Comment: Yes, I am in Pycharm. I just tried importing selenium in idle and it worked fine but it doesn't import in Pycharm. But I need it to import in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to configure the python environment in Pycharm. To configure Python SDK for the current project, follow these steps:

- Open the Settings/Preferences dialog box, and click Project
- Interpreter page. In the Projects pane, choose the desired project.
- Choose SDK from the list of available Python interpreters and virtual
  environments.

Refer [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html) website for details

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you response. I was able to solve the problem using your advice. My solution was a little different than what you suggested. I opened Preferences in PyCharm and selected the project interpreter. At that point a window opened listing all the packages currently acknowledged by Pycharm. I then clicked on the + sign to add another package and scrolled down the list until I found selenium and then clicked install package. Once Pycharm installed the package the import works correctly. Thank you very much for your help it is greatly appreciated

Comment: @user3798654 Glad to help !